# Rails select field helper with a block not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview

I'm trying to pass a block to a rails `select` field helper to generate options with `data` attributes, but it results in an error. Am I doing it wrong?

My (simplified) example failing code looks like this:

```
<%= f.select :item do
      Item.all.each do |item|
        content_tag(:option, item.title)
      end
    end %>
```

The error is: `undefined method 'empty?' for nil:NilClass`. Which comes from `@choices` being nil on [this line of actionview](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/57bf92c6de125adc45bb006115d22d07270618b3/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/tags/select.rb#L36).

This is the Rails commit for the ability to use a block:

https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/57bf92c6de125adc45bb006115d22d07270618b3
https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/1c6bcefe7e87e1b9c7b2177717bbdc3986806391 (doc)

The docs suggest that it should work as I have it. What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue and spent a few hours digging around in rails until I had a good look at the test case.  So for the benefit of anyone else who ends up here with the same problem...

The trick is to use `concat` in the block:

```
<%= f.select :item do
  Item.all.each do |item|
    concat content_tag(:option, item.title)
  end
end %>
```

Looks like the example in the docs is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Move the lines into separate erb blocks, being explicit about which lines to output:

```
<%= f.select :item do %>
  <%- Item.all.each do |item| -%>
    <%= content_tag(:option, item.title) %>
  <%- end -%>
<%- end -%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= f.select :item do
  Item.all.collect do |item|
    [item.title, item.id]
  end
end %>
```

Or refer the [doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select).

Comment: Did you try your code? It gives the same error. Any array or enumerator results in the same error. And the code I posted in the question is a simplified version of the block example at the end of the doc example for 'available_campaigns'.